# How to join lines based on between only?

Tags: mysql

I am investigating the causality of two different entries in two DB tables with no common ID that I could link by.

The only thing I have is unix timestamp in one, and and a date time column in the other. I am pretty sure a certain operation triggers another one, but I need to double check.

So I tried something like this:

`SELECT * FROM requests
RIGHT JOIN log_service on (log_service.date is BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1512312363) and FROM_UNIXTIME(1512312363+2))`

For example I have row in requests table with timestamp_send as 1512312363, and I have two matching rows in log_service table with a date value that is like: 2017-12-03 16:46:02
2017-12-03 16:46:03
(Its GMT+2)

Therefore, I want to right join the log_service table, associating it with the request I am looking at.

The query attempt above does not work.
It returns:

`ELECT * FROM requests
RIGHT JOIN log_service on (log_service.date is BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1512312363) and FROM_UNIXTIME(1512312363+2))
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1512312363) and FROM_UNIXTIME(1512312363+2))' at line 2
Time: 0.189s`

Obviously the hardcoded number in the finished query would be the `requests.timestamp_send` column from the left table.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Please provide the table details (minimal) and some sample data. If possible please use sql fiddle

Comment: remove the spurious **`is`** between the column reference `log_service.date` and the `BETWEEN` keyword.  (The keyword `IS` is used for comparing to boolean; it's not part of the `BETWEEN` operator. (Reporting that the query "does not work" is so vague as to be practically useless.  Is the query returning an error? Not returning expected rows, returning too many rows?

Comment: @spencer7593 sorry, forgot to add the error response, added now.

Comment: @MHRasel I have to go now, I will add the information and ping you tomorrow, if no resolution by then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted in my comment to the question,  first, remove the spurious **`IS`** keyword before `BETWEEN`.  (The `IS` keyword is used for comparing boolean expressions, it's not a part of the `BETWEEN` comparison operator.)

For datetime range comparisons, we typically use a pattern of two comparisons, with only one side including the equality.

```
       foo >= start  AND  foo < end
```

There are some good several good write-ups about the reasons for this, and the unintentional errors that are introduced with `BETWEEN`. But this may not fit your paticular use case, where you really do want equality on both sides of the comparison. I would still recommend the pattern of two comparisons, even if it means we have to repeat an expression.

```
       foo >= start  AND  foo <= end
```

I also recommend ditching the `*` in the SELECT list, and specifically list the expressions the query is supposed to return. This gives the future reader the names of the columns, the number of columns, and more of an indication which columns are actually of interest.

Also, it seems like we are wanting to find the log_service rows that are associated with "the request I am looking at". That suggests that there may be some criteria that identify the row(s) from `request` we are interested in.

It also suggests we want to return the row from request, along with any matching rows from log_service... and that suggests the outer join would be the other way around, a `LEFT` join rather than a `RIGHT` join.

The next issue is identifying the actual datatypes of the columns involved in the "date" and "unix timestamp" comparison. Without that information, we're kind of just guessing...  `timestamp_send` column in `request` is INTEGER type and contains unix-style number of seconds since the beginning of the epoch, and the `date` column in `log_service` is DATETIME.

Based on the specification provided, we would tend to write a query like this:

```
SELECT rq.timestamp_send                AS rq_timestamp_send
     , FROM_UNIXTIME(rq.timestamp_send) AS rq_datetime_send
     , ls.date
     , ls.foo
     , ...
  FROM requests rq
  LEFT
  JOIN log_service ls
    ON ls.date >= FROM_UNIXTIME( rq.timestamp_send )
   AND ls.date  < FROM_UNIXTIME( rq.timestamp_send ) + INTERVAL 3 SECOND
 WHERE rq.somecol = 'the request i am looking at'
```

Comment: Thank you!! works perfectly with slight adjustment. And all assumptions were correct about column types, hehe.